# C# XElement is not getting multiple Values for the same Tag multiple times

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I have this .graphml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:java="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/1.0/java" xmlns:sys="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/markup/primitives/2.0" xmlns:x="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/markup/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:y="http://www.yworks.com/xml/graphml" xmlns:yed="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yed/3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://www.yworks.com/xml/schema/graphml/1.1/ygraphml.xsd">
  <!--Created by yEd 3.19.1-->
  <key for="port" id="d0" yfiles.type="portgraphics"/>
  <key for="port" id="d1" yfiles.type="portgeometry"/>
  <key for="port" id="d2" yfiles.type="portuserdata"/>
  <key attr.name="url" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d3"/>
  <key attr.name="description" attr.type="string" for="node" id="d4"/>
  <key for="node" id="d5" yfiles.type="nodegraphics"/>
  <key for="graphml" id="d6" yfiles.type="resources"/>
  <key attr.name="url" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d7"/>
  <key attr.name="description" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d8"/>
  <key for="edge" id="d9" yfiles.type="edgegraphics"/>
  <graph edgedefault="directed" id="G">
    <node id="n0">
      <data key="d5">
        <y:UMLClassNode>
          <y:Geometry height="116.0" width="131.0" x="1301.3333333333333" y="41.0"/>
          <y:Fill color="#FFCC00" transparent="false"/>
          <y:BorderStyle color="#000000" type="line" width="1.0"/>
          <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" autoSizePolicy="content" fontFamily="Dialog" fontSize="12" fontStyle="bold" hasBackgroundColor="false" hasLineColor="false" height="18.701171875" horizontalTextPosition="center" iconTextGap="4" modelName="internal" modelPosition="c" textColor="#000000" verticalTextPosition="bottom" visible="true" width="138.7421875" x="-3.87109375" xml:space="preserve" y="3.0">&lt;&lt;interface&gt;&gt;Employee</y:NodeLabel>
          <y:UML clipContent="true" constraint="" hasDetailsColor="false" omitDetails="false" stereotype="" use3DEffect="true">
            <y:AttributeLabel xml:space="preserve">+name:string
+age:int</y:AttributeLabel>
            <y:MethodLabel xml:space="preserve">getName(value:string):String
getTitle():String
getStaffNo():Number
getRoom():String
getPhone()</y:MethodLabel>
          </y:UML>
        </y:UMLClassNode>
      </data>
    </node>
    <node id="n1">
      <data key="d3" xml:space="preserve"/>
      <data key="d4"/>
      <data key="d5">
        <y:UMLClassNode>
          <y:Geometry height="116.0" width="206.0" x="1422.0" y="197.0"/>
          <y:Fill color="#FFCC00" transparent="false"/>
          <y:BorderStyle color="#000000" type="line" width="1.0"/>
          <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" autoSizePolicy="content" fontFamily="Dialog" fontSize="13" fontStyle="bold" hasBackgroundColor="false" hasLineColor="false" height="19.92626953125" horizontalTextPosition="center" iconTextGap="4" modelName="custom" textColor="#000000" verticalTextPosition="bottom" visible="true" width="64.67724609375" x="70.661376953125" xml:space="preserve" y="3.0">Customer<y:LabelModel><y:SmartNodeLabelModel distance="4.0"/></y:LabelModel><y:ModelParameter><y:SmartNodeLabelModelParameter labelRatioX="0.0" labelRatioY="0.0" nodeRatioX="0.0" nodeRatioY="0.0" offsetX="0.0" offsetY="0.0" upX="0.0" upY="-1.0"/></y:ModelParameter></y:NodeLabel>
          <y:UML clipContent="true" constraint="" hasDetailsColor="false" omitDetails="false" stereotype="" use3DEffect="true">
            <y:AttributeLabel xml:space="preserve">+name:string</y:AttributeLabel>
            <y:MethodLabel xml:space="preserve">+getOrder():string
+payOrder(order:string):int</y:MethodLabel>
          </y:UML>
        </y:UMLClassNode>
      </data>
    </node>
    <node id="n2">
      <data key="d3" xml:space="preserve"/>
      <data key="d4"/>
      <data key="d5">
        <y:UMLClassNode>
          <y:Geometry height="86.0" width="100.0" x="1086.0" y="197.0"/>
          <y:Fill color="#FFCC00" transparent="false"/>
          <y:BorderStyle color="#000000" type="line" width="1.0"/>
          <y:NodeLabel alignment="center" autoSizePolicy="content" fontFamily="Dialog" fontSize="13" fontStyle="bold" hasBackgroundColor="false" hasLineColor="false" height="19.92626953125" horizontalTextPosition="center" iconTextGap="4" modelName="custom" textColor="#000000" verticalTextPosition="bottom" visible="true" width="32.9072265625" x="33.54638671875" xml:space="preserve" y="3.0">User<y:LabelModel><y:SmartNodeLabelModel distance="4.0"/></y:LabelModel><y:ModelParameter><y:SmartNodeLabelModelParameter labelRatioX="0.0" labelRatioY="0.0" nodeRatioX="0.0" nodeRatioY="0.0" offsetX="0.0" offsetY="0.0" upX="0.0" upY="-1.0"/></y:ModelParameter></y:NodeLabel>
          <y:UML clipContent="true" constraint="" hasDetailsColor="false" omitDetails="false" stereotype="" use3DEffect="true">
            <y:AttributeLabel xml:space="preserve">+name:string</y:AttributeLabel>
            <y:MethodLabel xml:space="preserve">getName()</y:MethodLabel>
          </y:UML>
        </y:UMLClassNode>
      </data>
    </node>
  </graph>
  <data key="d6">
    <y:Resources/>
  </data>
</graphml>
```

This code:

```
public List<Key> AnalyzeNode(XmlReader reader, string filepath)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<Key> keys = doc.Descendants(ns + "node").Select(x => new Key()
            {
                id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                baseModel = AnalyzeNodeLabel<UML_Base>(reader, (string)x.Attribute("id"))
            }).ToList();
           return keys;
       }
```

```
        public T AnalyzeNodeLabel<T>(XmlReader reader, string id) where T : UML_Base
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(this.filepath);
                XNamespace ns = "http://www.yworks.com/xml/graphml";
                XElement element = doc.Descendants(ns + "NodeLabel").FirstOrDefault();

                string interfaceName = element.Value;

                    if (interfaceName.Contains("&lt;&lt;interface&gt;&gt;") || interfaceName.Contains("interface") || interfaceName.StartsWith("I") && interfaceName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper().Equals(interfaceName))
                    {
                        UML_Interface interfaceModel = new UML_Interface(interfaceName, id);
                        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(interfaceModel, typeof(UML_Interface));
                    }
                    if (interfaceName != null && !interfaceName.Contains("&lt;&lt;interface&gt;&gt;") || !interfaceName.Contains("interface") || !interfaceName.StartsWith("I") && !interfaceName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper().Equals(interfaceName))
                    {
                        UML_Class classModel = new UML_Class(interfaceName, id);
                        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(classModel, typeof(UML_Class));
                    }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

and my problem is the `XElement`is getting just one value but there are 3 `<y:NodeLabel>`Tags with different values. With Values I mean the Text. But my XElement Object (`from AnalyzeNodeLabel()`) is just getting the Value from the first `<y:NodeLabel>` tag and how can I add the others ones also? Maybe as List? or updating the Value after one loop? Is that possible?

Comment: Use : List<XElement> elements = doc.Descendants(yns + "NodeLabel").ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly select the first occurrence of the node: **FirstOrDefault()**
You have to select the nodes in a loop:

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants(ns + "NodeLabel"))
{
    ...
}
```

**Update:**
I don't know why you opened the Xml-File twice or what is happend with the XmlReader.
If you are only interested in the nodes "node" and "NodeLabel" (perhaps more than one) then this might help:

```
XNamespace yns = "http://www.yworks.com/xml/graphml";
Dictionary<string, List<string>> keys = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (var node in doc.Descendants(ns + "node"))
{
    keys[node.Attribute("id").Value] = new List<string>();
    foreach (var nodeLabel in node.Descendants(yns + "NodeLabel"))
    {
        keys[node.Attribute("id").Value].Add(nodeLabel.Value);
    }
}

foreach (var entry in keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {entry.Key}");
    foreach (var basemodel in entry.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"->basemodel: {basemodel}");
    }
}
```

Output is:
Key: n0
->basemodel: << interface >>Employee 
Key: n1
->basemodel: Customer
Key: n2
->basemodel: User

Comment: Yes you're right but when I am doing this, I am getting all different element.Values but the id is always the same because of calling the method with `x.Attribute("id")` Value of one object that was created. I need the other Id's as well

Comment: If you select this: List<string> keys = doc.Descendants(ns + "node").Select(x => x.Attribute("id").Value).ToList();. You get n0, n1, n2.

Comment: what about the baseModel?  all objects need id and the baseModel which contains element.value.

Comment: Thank you for your update, but with your methode I am getting for each id all basemodels. So n0 --> has <<interface>>Employee,Customer,User and n1 ---> has <<interface>>Employee,Customer,User and n2 ---> has <<interface>>Employee,Customer,User

Comment: Not with the method in the example

Comment: Sorry you're right its working fine and like I wanted! Thank you so much